# can't exclude META-INF from APK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, apk

I'm having trouble with APK building, from ionic project.

When I verify my APK with apksigner, I got :

```
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

I have searched, and it seems I have to exclude the file "META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader"

But, in my build.gradle which is in "platforms/android/app" folder, if I add :

```
packagingOptions {

    exclude 'META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader'

}
```

inside android { }, I still got the same error, as if the exclude line was not interpreted ...

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I can exclude each offending file in META-INF but not in META-INF/services.